# D3v4 timeParse always returns null

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have this D3js code:

```
var dataset=JSON.parse('{"date": ["2016-11-28", "2016-11-29", "2016-12-01", "2016-12-02", "2016-12-03", "2016-12-04", "2016-12-05", "2016-12-06", "2016-12-07", "2016-12-08", "2016-12-09", "2016-12-10", "2016-12-11"], "bca": [{"JPY": 119, "USD": 13510, "SGD": 9455, "CNY": 1944}, {"JPY": 120, "USD": 13527, "SGD": 9491, "CNY": 1951}, {"JPY": 118, "USD": 13560, "SGD": 9459, "CNY": 1959}, {"JPY": 119, "USD": 13535, "SGD": 9498, "CNY": 1968}, {"JPY": 118, "USD": 13485, "SGD": 9470, "CNY": 1958}, {"JPY": 118, "USD": 13485, "SGD": 9470, "CNY": 1958}, {"JPY": 118, "USD": 13485, "SGD": 9470, "CNY": 1958}, {"JPY": 117, "USD": 13430, "SGD": 9435, "CNY": 1952}, {"JPY": 117, "USD": 13382, "SGD": 9426, "CNY": 1944}, {"JPY": 116, "USD": 13327, "SGD": 9379, "CNY": 1931}, {"JPY": 117, "USD": 13278, "SGD": 9375, "CNY": 1926}, {"JPY": 116, "USD": 13322, "SGD": 9360, "CNY": 1923}, {"JPY": 116, "USD": 13322, "SGD": 9360, "CNY": 1923}], "maybank": [{"JPY": 119, "USD": 13510, "SGD": 9463, "CNY": 1945}, {"JPY": 120, "USD": 13520, "SGD": 9487, "CNY": 1951}, {"JPY": 119, "USD": 13550, "SGD": 9509, "CNY": 1964}, {"JPY": 118, "USD": 13540, "SGD": 9466, "CNY": 1961}, {"JPY": 118, "USD": 13490, "SGD": 9477, "CNY": 1961}, {"JPY": 118, "USD": 13490, "SGD": 9477, "CNY": 1961}, {"JPY": 118, "USD": 13490, "SGD": 9477, "CNY": 1961}, {"JPY": 117, "USD": 13420, "SGD": 9428, "CNY": 1951}, {"JPY": 117, "USD": 13380, "SGD": 9426, "CNY": 1944}, {"JPY": 116, "USD": 13330, "SGD": 9373, "CNY": 1931}, {"JPY": 116, "USD": 13270, "SGD": 9368, "CNY": 1926}, {"JPY": 116, "USD": 13320, "SGD": 9358, "CNY": 1923}, {"JPY": 116, "USD": 13320, "SGD": 9358, "CNY": 1923}]}');
var svg = d3.select(".tes").append("svg").attr("width", 800).attr("height", 450);
var parsetime = d3.timeParse("%y-%m-%d");
var ya=[];
for (var i=0;i<dataset['date'].length;i++){
     ya.push({"x":parsetime(dataset['date'][i]),"y":dataset['maybank'][i]['JPY']});
}
var xS = d3.scaleTime().range([0,750]);
var yS = d3.scaleLinear().range([400,0]);
var valueline = d3.line().x(function(d){return xS(d.x);}).y(function(d){return yS(d.y);});
xS.domain([d3.extent(ya, function(d) { return d.x; })]);
yS.domain([0, d3.max(ya, function(d) { return d.y; })]);
svg.append("path").data([ya]).attr("class","line").attr("d", valueline);
svg.append('g').attr("transform", "translate(35,"+ 400 +")").call(d3.axisBottom(xS));
svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + 35 + ",0)").call(d3.axisLeft(yS));
```

I found out that parseTime always returns a null. So the line graph can't be created. Does parseTime have to be inside the d3 data function, e.g. d3.tsv, d3.json, etc? But from my json data it would be difficult to make. Or any other suggestion to make this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format specifier `%y-%m-%d` is incorrect.

According to the [D3 documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format), `%y` is the directive for a 2-digit year and `%Y` is the one for a 4-digit year.   You are using 4-digit years so you need `%Y` instead of `%y`.

Comment: oh sorry. I didn't realize it. Thanks anyway